# Push committed files in PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have committed some files to Git using PyCharm. Now I want to push them but I don't see such an option.

[image]

Comment: There is a push action. Open action list and type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform git push by selecting from `VCS` -> `Git` -> `Push` button